# SVG <defs> not included from external target of <use>

Tags: svg

Given an SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="60" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="clipped">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <circle cx="35" cy="20" r="10"/>
      <circle cx="25" cy="20" r="10"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <rect x="5" y="5" width="50" height="30" fill="red"
  clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>
</svg>
```

If that files is included as an external `use` in the following HTML:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<hmtl>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 60 120">
        <use href="above.svg#clipped" x="0" y="0"></use>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `<clipPath>s` in the `<def>` section are ignored/not included and so a solid red rectangle is displayed instead of being clipped to show as to overlapping circles.

I don't know why this happens or how to make it not happen. I'm worried this is working as intended but I have been unable to find any source (definitive or otherwise) that explains why this happens.

It's a surprisingly difficult thing to google or search StackOverflow for given the terms required to explain the problem and their overloaded meaning.

I have a [demo of the problem here](https://bl.ocks.org/Binarytales/b223bd249da0228b461b6eaf4fd139ab) too.

Comment: Using Chrome to inspect the Shadow DOM of the included SVG it looks like the <defs> are not even present. Like as if they are discarded before the Shadow DOM is inserted.

Comment: Oh man. I spent like nearly 2 days searching for what was going on here and got nothing. Mad props to Robert Longson for finding the duplicate.